# What is wrong with my hydrangea

Tags: plant-health, containers

I believe my hydrangea has powdery mildew which was present when I bought it but got worse. I don't overhead water. I sprayed with a baking soda mix yesterday and think it helped but noticed how bad the plant looks even after this. A couple of months ago I used (I think) a Seasol fertiliser on it and noticed the sides of the leaves browning. I haven't used it since, but the browning is getting worse. I am watering less now that the weather is colder (in Melbourne). The leaves have what I would describe as a light green and yellow mottled appearance. Thanks.

[image: My hydrangea]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hydrangeas are deciduous, so the discoloration is likely down to natural processes that take place as the leaves are about to be discarded.

Otherwise, Hydrangeas,depending on variety, are large plants - you don't say how long you've had the plant, but it won't do terribly well contained in a pot for very long,though they will do longer if you pot on into larger containers as time goes by. Still better planted in the ground though I'm afraid.